# Container Hyperledger/fabric-tools cli doesn't run for Go chaincode example Hyperledger v2

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using the guide: https://stone-fabric.readthedocs.io/zh/release-2.0_en-us/chaincode4ade.html

When i run: *docker-compose -f docker-compose-simple.yaml up* shows me that the orderer, peer, chaincode and cli starting correctly. [image]

When i build and start the chaincode, the things not go wrong either:
[image]

But when i try to use the chaincode with the cli it shows me "Container is not running".
[image]

Then i figured out that the hyperledger/fabric-tools cli never start and i can't make it work. [image]

I tried to start it manually using docker but doesn't work neither.
[image]

My code is exactly as the Hyperledger example.

If someone can help me i'll be grateful.

Answer (score -1):

I find out the docker-compose show me a "cli exit with 1" so i made  some search and only comment the line: "command: /bin/bash -c './script.sh'" and it works perfectly.